# How should the description of anime/manga title tags be written?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have created two new tags (though one was created for me because I was too slow!). One for [clannad] and for [reborn]. 
I set the description out like this. I'll be using Kuroshitsuji/Black Butler as an example:

> A shounen manga and anime, focusing on the avenging young boy who is known as the "Queen's Loyal Dog", Ciel Phantomhive and his curious, cat-loving, demon butler, Sebastian Michaelis.

I thought it was good because it gives a description of the main characters and their names - plus a short and not too revealing snippet of the story. I thought the genre was also an important feature. The template I would use would be:

> A [genre] anime [and/or] manga, focusing on the live(s) of the [short description], [main character's name] and the [short dedcription], [main characters nane].

For another example, Full Metal Alchemist:

> A shounen manga and anime, focusing on the lives and adventures of the brothers - a short, bad-tempered but alchemistically talented Edward Elric and his brother, a gracious, polite and loving young boy with a hardship beyond fair, Alphonse Elric.

Or Chobits, perhaps:

> A seinen anime and manga focused on the farm-boy come Tokyo University Motosua and his encounter with a gorgeous and glowing personal computer robot, known as a 'persocom' named Chii.

I didn't really know how a should do them properly, so I thought I may as well discuss the idea. I don't mean for it to be sent in concrete, but just as a trial-and-error theory.

Answer (score 1):

I think the format you suggested is quite good, the genre and main character(s) is important, but I will also like to suggest including the theme or plot direction, something like:

> A shounen manga and anime, focusing on the lives and adventures of two
>   brothers; Edward and Alphonse Elric, who through a series of events
>   studies and uses alchemy in their search for the legendary
>   philosopher's stone.

Comment: I agree. I quite like your addition! :P